# Is it possible for a user to interact with my web site before all document ready handlers have run?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is not possible for the user to interact with the page before the document ready event fires - we're pretty sure that this is guaranteed, but would love a W3 link for that as well.

We've registered some JQuery-based document ready handlers - are those guaranteed to be run before the user can interact with the page as well?

Comment: There is an amount of time in the page lifecycle where it is possible for the user to interact with the DOM before it has fully loaded. The length of this will depend on the connection speed of the client, and the size of the content being downloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's entirely possible.

The Ready event doesn't fire until the entire DOM has been loaded (i.e. the HTML document has been fully parsed).

Since browsers use progressive rendering, the document can be interacted with before then.

Comment: So, https://api.jquery.com/ready/ is lying when they tell me "This will often be a good time to perform tasks that are needed before the user views or interacts with the page, for example to add event handlers and initialize plugins." - because it could be too late?

Comment: @JonasWilms Yeah ... let's say "misleading" instead of "lying".

Comment: @Quentin: So it's "the best you get with HTML, but in general, there is no way to execute code before the user can interact with the page" - is that correct?

Comment: @D.R. — Sure you can. Put the script in the head. Run the JS outside of an event handler.

Comment: I've created an issue here https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4455 to clarify the docs. Thanks again!

Comment: @D.R. You have oversimplified in that issue what can and can't be done before elements exist when running code from head

Comment: @charlietfl: Please contribute to the GitHub issue so it will become clearer! Thank you! (I don't see what exactly I have over-simplified)

Comment: @D.R. the point is you can't manipulate elements or add listeners to them until they exist. So there are limitations to exactly what can be done from head without load event listeners.